# Rails 3 to_i method susbtitute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, string, methods, integer, type-conversion

I have a string variable `codigo = "0001"` that I want to convert to an integer and increment its value by 1, I used to do this with `codigo.to_i += 1` but apparently that method has been deprecated in Rails 3. Which is the Rails 3 way to do this now?

Comment: What's been deprecated? The `+=` method or the `to_i` method? `to_i` is a Ruby method. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_i

Comment: The `to_i` method is no longer a type converter method in Rails 3, I'm looking for a method that does the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic problem here is that your variable, `codigo`, is a String.

`codigo.to_i` will return an integer, but it doesn't change the type of the variable it's called on, so it's still a String, you've just called a method on it that returns an integer.

`codigo.to_i + 1` would return 2.

`codigo.to_1 += 1` will produce an error because the return value isn't in any variable, so it can't be incremented.

So, to convert the variable to an integer and increment that, do this:

```
codigo = codigo.to_i
codigo += 1
```

If it makes more sense, you can also do this in one line:

```
codigo = codigo.to_i + 1
```